# JavaScript Memory Leak - Garbage Collection on DOM Nodes and descendants

Tags: javascript, dom, garbage-collection

In modern browsers, DOM Nodes are removed from memory by the garbage collector provided they have no references pointing to them (special case for event listeners*)

I'm looking for some clarity about DOM descendant nodes. I assume that descendant relations are one-way parent->child. So if the parent node is not attached to the DOM and has no references, it will be collected, and you get a domino effect for the child elements. Is this correct?

Or is it necessary to walk the Nodes and detach all of them?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: *"I assume that descendant relations are one-way parent->child."* Well, every node also has a `.parent` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that descendant relations are one-way parent->child.

No, those relations are bi-directional.

But that does not matter to garbage collectors (at least not the mark-sweep kind), because garbage collectors only care about reachability, not about the connectedness of objects.
If reference-counting is used you need a cycle collector to detect this situation but then the whole subtree can still be collected without disconnecting the children first.

> Or is it necessary to walk the Nodes and detach all of them?

That isn't necessary, no. Unless you intend to hold references to some descendant node but still want other parts of the disconnected tree collected.

> Can I ask if this applies to eventListeners with anonymous functions referencing the nodes

If the anonymous function has the dom node itself (or another object holding the dom node) in its scope chain then it depends on whether something else holds onto the function instance.

More generally speaking: *Any* object is eligible for garbage collection *unless* it is reachable from a GC root.

In first approximation the primary GC root in browsers is the global/window object. If the window object goes away, everything else does.

Paths from GC roots can be very long and complex, so in some circumstances one has to reason about them carefully.
DOM nodes reference their callback functions which reference their scope chains which could reference other dom nodes and so on.

Comment: "garbage collectors only care about reachability"
So it's not lack of references? It's lack of references to lead back to the DOM or script execution? That's really useful! Can I ask if this applies to eventListeners with anonymous functions referencing the nodes, or should I post a new question?